# How do I set the versions of iOS supported in my app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My app is in the app store, and I realized that it won't work on iOS5 and lower devices due to the usage of AutoLayout. Is there a way I can restrict the download to work only for iOS6+ devices in iTunesConnect? Or do I have to resubmit the binary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the *Deployment Target* parameter in the target settings of your project. Here's an example that sets it to >=5.0

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This would involve resubmitting it correct? And if its already on sale for >iOS6, what exactly would happen?

Comment: @Carpetfizz Or submitting an update, perhaps with an additional feature so that it won't be a useless update ;)

Comment: Yes, it involves resubmitting the binary. It's strange that Apple allowed your app on the store if it crashes with iOS5. In any case the availability is determined by the target setting

Comment: @Simon M Thanks! So for people using iOS5, they can't even see it on the store?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella I was surprised too. I knew this was an issue when I submitted it, but I was unaware that you can manually change the target version. Thought that Apple would set it to the version necessary. EDIT: Yours is the right answer, but I have to wait 6 minutes to accept it haha. Thanks again.

Comment: @Carpetfizz Yes it's odd. In any case that's exactly what happens: only users who can install your app (as specified by your target settings) will see it on the store. There is (usually) no such thing as a "Device not supported" error message presented to the final user

Comment: In practice, we've recently seen Apple testing apps with only the latest major iOS version.

Comment: At the same time, Apple's verification team is not there to do some QA on every app. It's the developper's responsability to make sure his/her app is working correctly on every supported version of iOS.